# Calculate end date with java.time.Duration (ISO 8601) as input?

Tags: java, date, duration

I have duration parsed and ready, Duration is of type java.time.Duration with this as input I have tried to calculate end datetime by adding LocalDateTime.now() with duration (java.time.duration). But haven't got appropriate results

Was able to see that there is something on similar lines with ReadableDuration, but not much documentation on how to use it.

```
java.time.Duration duration = java.time.Duration.parse(timeinISOSTD);
Date localDate =  (Date) duration.addTo(java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
String stringDate = localDate.toString();
```

I need an end date-time Or end date object which will help me in determining SLA end DateTime.

Comment: "haven't got appropriate results" is not a useful description. What, specifically, did you expect, and what, specifically, did you obtain? What is the value of `timeinISOSTD`?

Comment: Shouldn't that cast to `Date` fail?

Comment: and more, what is `Date` (java.util or java.sql, or ...) - actually it should not be possible to cast a `LocalDateTime` (returned by `addto`) to `Date` - why not `LocalDateTime.now().plus(duration)` which does not require cast....

Comment: **Don't. Use. `Date`.** You are on the right track by already using classes from the `java.time` package, but you should also drop `Date` altogether. Unless you absolutely have to – but you don't.

Comment: @OleV.V. done, but hard to know what really are the expected "appropriate results"

Comment: Be aware that `LocalDateTime` is for generic 24-hour days, and *not* for actual moments. If your tracking actual elapsed time, you should be using `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: What do you mean by "SLA"?

Comment: What do you mean by `ReadableDuration`? There is no such class bundled with Java.

Comment: @BasilBourque SLA = service level agreement, `ReadableDuration` confusing something from Joda-Time. Not that my guesses are better than yours…

Comment: @OleV.V. It is up to the OP to explain their use of acronyms and their relevance.

Answer (score 4):

I will suppose that parsing is working, that is, `duration` has got a valid value. The statement

`(Date) duration.addTo(java.time.LocalDateTime.now());`

should throw an Exception. According the documentation of [`addTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#addTo(java.time.temporal.Temporal))

> This returns a temporal object of the same observable type as the input...

it must be returning a `LocalDateTime` which is not a `Date`, that is, the cast will throw an Exception (should have been posted with the question, so I can only assume that was the problem).

Simple solution:

```
LocalDateTime localDate = (LocalDateTime) duration.addTo(java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
```

Or, even better, also as suggested by the same documentation

> In most cases, it is clearer to reverse the calling pattern...

that is:

```
LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.now().plus(duration);
```

<sup>Note: to get this formatted as a String use the `format` method with a `DateTimeFormatter` for the needed representation, e.g. `localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))`</sup>

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
Instant                   // Represent a moment in UTC, with a resolution of nanoseconds.
.now()                    // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC. Returns an `Instant` object.
.plus(                    // Add a span-of-time, resulting in a different moment.
    Duration              // Represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline on the scale of hours-minutes-seconds.
    .parse( "PT3H" )      // Parse a string in standard ISO 8601 format. Returns a `Duration` object.
)                         // Returns another `Instant` object.
```

## Details

You seem to be unwisely mixing different kinds of data types.

- [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) represents a date and a time-of-day without a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it *cannot* represent a moment. Do **not** use this class if you are tracking actual moments in time.
- `Date`, both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`, are terrible legacy classes that should never be used. They were supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes years ago with the adoption of JSR 310. Specifically, [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) replaces the first, and [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) replaces the second.
- [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) represents a span of days (in terms of 24-hour chunks of time, **not** calendar days), hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional second. For a span-of-time in terms of years-months-days, use `Period`.

> LocalDateTime.now()

I cannot think of any situation where this call is the right thing to do. As mentioned above, this class by definition cannot represent a moment. So trying to capture the current moment as `LocalDateTime` is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Apparently you want to parse a string representing a number of hours-minutes-seconds. Easy to do if your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String input = "PT4H30M" ;           // Four-and-a-half hours.
Duration duration = Duration.parse( input ) ;
```

Then you apparently want to capture the current moment.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;    // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
```

And lastly you want to add the span-of-time to that current moment.

```
Instant later = instant.plus( duration ) ;
```

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for this new moment.

```
String output = later.toString() ;
```